# The function is diffeomorphism

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define $$ \phi:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to (-1,1)\times(-1,1) $$ defined by, $\phi(u,v)=\left(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2},\frac{v}{u^2+v^2}\right)$.

I am facing problem in finding out the inverse of this function. Please help me.

Comment: This function can't be a diffeomorphism, as the domain is non-compact but the codomain is compact. It could be a local diffeomorphism though, which you can check by computing the Jacobian and using the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Okay, I got it, that was my mistake.

Comment: I changed it.  There was  a mistake, it was not closed interval but open set.

Comment: The new choice of the codomain does not work either. Hint: Compose $\phi$ with itself.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\phi$ is its own inverse if we consider $\phi:\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.   The resulting map is a diffeomorphism ...

This $\phi$ is "reflection" of a point about the unit circle...